# Tomcat 8 how to remove sessionCookieName from URL

Tags: java, tomcat, session-cookies

I have changed the `sessionCookieName` in context.xml

```
<Context sessionCookieName="SESSIONID">
    ...
</Context>
```

*Edit after @denov's answer:* In my web.xml I'm using this configuration:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Now I can see the new cookie name in my url:

> http://localhost:8080/profile;SESSIONID=FEB1091BD2E132362FFDE8FE354F4CEA

**It happen never** if I'm using default tomcat settings (JSESSIONID)

So how to disable this "feature"?

Comment: the link you provided ,is of your localhost server and its useless here

Comment: @holidayCoder so then, read the question again. it is just an example...

Answer (score 4):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

```
<Context sessionCookieName="SESSIONID" cookies="true">
...
</Context>
```

Comment: @denov: Linked doc states that the attribute name is "cookie**s**" (plural).

Comment: I don't think tracking-mode is valid for tomcat 8. I believe that was a tomcat 7 things.  It appears that tomcat 8 uses camel case for attributes and remove 'tracking-mode'   https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html

Comment: **tracking-mode** works with any Servlet 3.0-compliant servlet container which Tomcat 7.0.x onwards is already. For me it works fine on tomcat 8.0. https://fralef.me/tomcat-disable-jsessionid-in-url.html